# why does the Fourier algebra $A(G)$ consits precisely with the set of matrix coefficients of the LRR?

Tags: operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding Thm 2.4.3 (for second countable locally compact groups G" of "Fourier and FourierStieltjes Algebras on
Locally Compact Groups" by Kaniuth and Lau.

Context: The Fourier Algebra $A(G)$ of a (say second countable) lc group $G$ is defined to be the closed linear span of functions of the coefficients of the left regular representation, i.e. functions of the form $u(x)=\langle \pi(x)\xi,\eta\rangle=\xi*\breve{\eta}$ with respect to a certain norm. They then show that $A(G)$ is isometrically isomorphic to the predual (=space of ultraweak continuous functionals) of the group von Neumann algebra $VN(G)$. So far so good.

Now 2.4.3 asserts (see image 1): $A(G)$ consits *precisely* of the coefficients of the LRR (hence, we may drop both, span and closure in the definition). And here comes the part which I don't understand at all: Neither do I understand why Proposition 14.5.1, Dixmier (see image 2) implies that every normal positive functional on $VN(G)$ is of the form $T\mapsto \langle T\xi,\xi\rangle$, nor do I understand why this implies that every uwc-functional on $VN(G)$ is of the form $T\mapsto \langle T \xi,\eta \rangle$.

Thank you very much in advance for clarifying!

[image: Kaniuth Lau]

[image: Dixmier]

Comment: Now asked on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424100/why-does-the-fourier-algebra-ag-consits-precisely-of-the-set-of-matrix-coeff   You will probably get an answer there, but let me just say that in my opinion, this reference to Dixmier Proposition 14.5.1 is just wrong: there is no way this result is relevant.  I spent a bit of time trying to see if this was a typo (e.g. the correct reference is 13.5.1 or something) but I cannot find an obvious mistake.  Maybe it should be to [59] (which is the French version of Dixmier's von Neumann algebra book)?

Comment: Thank you for your help! And yeah, I also pretty convinced now that this is a typo... :D